# How to communicate between two pods with nodejs application

Tags: networking, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have two nodejs application, one as fronted and one ad backed. I am trying to run the application using kubernetes and not sure what to mention in serverProxy to connect to api which is running in different pod.

```
serverProxy: {
    apiA: process.env.API_A_PROXY || "https://localhost:4200"
}
```

What should i mention in above code of frontend node application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application is a real frontend, then it does not *run* in a pod, it runs in clients browser, and is only served from a pod. In that case you need to expose your api either with `LoadBalancer` type `Service` or via `Ingress`.

In case of LB Service you will point your app to `http://<lb_ip>:<port>`. In case of ingress, you will have to provide a DNS name pointing to LB IP of `Ingress Controller`, and then point your app to that name.

If that were only about pod-to-pod communication, then you should use ClusterIP type service and point to that service name which will be resolved within cluster ( Pod A -> Service B -> Pod B )

Comment: so if my service name is - my-service and i have to put the hostName as https://my-service. Is that what you mean

Comment: I am trying this on minikube, am not sure if load balance will work on that

Comment: You may find this tutorial helpful [https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/expose/expose-intro/](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/expose/expose-intro/)